# When to use Procs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have read several books on Ruby and I understand how Procs are created and called.  But the examples in these books are contrived and trivial.  I was wondering when is it actually useful to use a Proc as opposed to using a traditional way to do the same thing? Maybe someone could post a non-trivial example?

Comment: What do you consider a “traditional way to do the same thing”?

Comment: I guess I mean calling a method with the code I want pre-defined inside it instead of converting a block to a Proc and then calling said Proc.

Comment: proc/lambda are used everywhere in Ruby... like each, map, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html) is a great way to store a little bit of code that you want to run later in an object.  Blocks are not objects, but they can be easily converted to Procs.  Procs are useful for lots of things.  Procs are commonly used to implement [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).  I recently used Procs when I was writing a simulation of a system.  Each time I called the `step` method on my simulation, I wanted various things to happen.  I did not want the simulation object itself to know the details about those things; I just wanted it to call the callbacks that I defined.  I could have accomplished the same thing by defining a bunch of custom classes or objects that each have a `call` method, but using Procs was definitely simpler.

```
class X
  def initialize
    @step_callbacks = []
  end

  def every_step(&proc)
    # If you print proc.class here, you can see it is a Proc
    @step_callbacks << proc
  end

  def step
    # ...perform the step...
    @step_callbacks.each do |proc|
      proc.call
    end
  end
end

x = X.new

x.every_step do
  # check some assertions about the state of the simulation
end

x.every_step do
  # update a related simulation
end

x.step
x.step
```

I hope you don't think this example is contrived.  I did use it to get work done at my job.  Also I used the same pattern to handle received packets in my minecraft bot, [as you can see here](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/redstone-bot2/blob/2edecc6fe1903c0dd506ebd7ef58286246f94c34/lib/redstone_bot/client.rb#L79-91).

Callbacks are very useful whenever you want to have some object call some code but you don't want it to know exactly what code it is calling.  Procs are a simple way to implement callbacks.

Comment: This question is out of ignorance...why not just make every block you're turning into a Proc into a method instead?

Comment: That would take more lines of code and require you to make up new method names.  Also, it might require you to make an extra object to receive that method call.

Answer (score 0):

Proc is an object, so you can create complex objects that include them. For example, you can create a hash that matches keys to instructions:

```
object1 = {
  :foo => ->{execute_foo_routine},
  :bar => ->{execute_bar_routine},
  ...
}
...
object1[:foo].call # => execution
```

Note that all information is included within `object1`. This is useful when you want to encapsule all necessary information and make it independent of outer code. `object1` is portable.

If you wanted to do that using methods, then not all information can be put inside the object, but the methods need to be defined somewhere else:

```
object2 = {
  :foo => :foo_routine,
  :bar => :bar_routine,
  ...
}

def foo_routine
  ...
end
def bar_routine
  ...
end
...
send(object2[:foo]) # => execution
```

and `object2` would not be as portable as `object1`.

Comment: This doesn't really demonstrate procs very well. Your first example uses `labmda` procs and your second example using `send` doesn't use procs at all. Also, aways use `public_send` over `send`.

Comment: @naomik You misread my answer. The "second example" you mention is an example of not using procs, posted as comparison to the example using procs.